# Integrate function under $L^2$ Norm

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

I am following the book of Salsa (2008), BTW very good book, and I found the this example that I can't really understand how he expanded the integral. Let's say you want to use the $L^2$ norm under a continuous function space $C(A)$, to test whether the space is complete using this norm:

$f_m = \begin{cases} 
         0& t \le 0 \\ 
         mt&0 < t \le 1/m\\
         1 & 1/m < t
       \end{cases} $

So for $m>k$,

$||f_m - f_k ||_{L^2(-1,1)}^2 = \int_{-1}^1 |f_m - f_k|^2 = \underbrace{(m-k)^2\int_0^{1/m}t^2 \, dt + \int_0^{1/k}(1-kt)^2 \, dt}_{\text{this I don't understand}}= \frac{(m-k)^2}{m^3} + \frac{1}{3k^3} $

To make it more clear, I do not follow how the limits of the integrals were chosen. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Side note: In `cases`-Environments, use `&` to separate the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy if you plot the two functions. If you do so, you'll see you can divide the integral in two parts: the intervals $[0,1/m]$ and $[1/m,1/k]$ (since $m>k$). The part $[-1,0]$ doesn't contribute, since both functions are 0 on that part, and they're constant 1 on $[1/k,1]$.

So, the interesting parts give us:
$$\int_0^{1/m} (mt-kt)^2dt + \int_{1/m}^{1/k}(1-kt)^2dt, $$
which is what you were looking for. The clue is using that $m>k$ and then using the definition of $f_m$ and $f_k$ to divide the interval in smaller pieces.

Edit: I see the second integral isn't exactly the same, so I assume you made an error copying it? Anyway, I believe this is the correct answer

Comment: I thought it was a problem with the lower bound on the second integral at first, but then the author solves the two integrals (I Edited my original post, please see the answer) which corresponds with his claim.